# How to use a mapping table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the 2 following table :

Source table with 2 columns (large number of records) :

```
columnA      columnB
abcdez       defghp
azerty       ghjklm
...
...
```

Mapping table with source value and new value. All columnA and columnB values in the source table have a matching value as source_value in the mapping table, with a corresponding new_value.

```
source_value      new_value
abcdez            123456
defghp            999999
azerty            444444
ghjklm            101010
...
...
...
```

I would like to use sql to build a view of my source table, with their replacement values from my mapping table :

View1 :

```
columnA       columnB
123456        999999
444444        101010
...
...
```

Thanks ahead for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the mapping table twice.

If you think of a join as a correlation between specific *rows* of each table, this makes a bit more sense.

```
SELECT m1.new_value AS columnA, m2.new_value AS columnB
FROM SourceTable AS s
JOIN MappingTable AS m1 ON s.columnA = m1.source_value
JOIN MappingTable AS m2 ON s.columnB = m2.source_value;
```

Comment: Thanks. makes sense indeed.
One last question : if a row in the source does not have a match in the mapping table. Will it be ignored. of will it return null ?

Comment: Inner join requires there is a row in the mapping table. If there isn't one, the join produces no row. If you have some missing rows, you should learn about outer joins. Any book or tutorial on SQL will cover that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.new_value as colA,t3.new_value as colb
from test1 t1 inner join test2 t2 on 
t1.cola=t2.source_value
inner join test2 t3 on 
t1.colb=t3.source_value
```

[image]